# Python json.loads return String

Tags: python, json

i have this [data](https://gist.github.com/nmorales1991/b1108f7d8ea893d83525aa6a63f6ebee) .

I parsed it to JSON and it worked for me some time ago

```
json_data = json.loads(data)
print(json_data['plp']['plp_products']) #OK
```

But now i have this error: `"TypeError: string indices must be integers".`
If i print the "type" of json_data, gives me a str :

`<class 'str'>`

How could I transform that data to use it again as a JSON? I especially need to work with the node `json_data['plp']['plp_products']`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reproduced your error. The root cause is your data was actually json encoded twice, which means you have to decode twice to get data.

```
json_data = json.loads(data)
json_data = json.loads(json_data)
```

Comment: Ha! This was it, thanks, saved my time.